# Can't authenticate user with pin. something wrong with the identitytoolkit API. I'm not new but i still dont have a clear idea about a lot

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I am developing an app where i authenticate users with their phone number using firebase. The app sends a code to the given phone number asking to verify and the user is signed up. I implemented this and it turned out fine a few months back. now when i try to delete the registered user and try registering again, it is throwing some error. This is the error shown:

> E/FirebaseAuth(17689): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode are blocked.
> D/FirebaseAuth(17689): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for "my-number", error - An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode are blocked. ]

I tried to register using my phone number but failed in doing so, I thought it would just work fine like it did earlier but instead threw the error shown above. This is my first question on stackoverflow so pardon me if the question is not clear:);